# Expo reload not working on Linux (with Android device)

Tags: linux, react-native, reload, expo, watchman

I'm having a problem with my expo app. It repently doesn't take my changes. Live reload, Hot reload doesn't work, and when I shake my device and press "reload", my app reload, but the changes doesn't appear.

What I already did:

- reinstall watchman
- delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, and run `$ npm install`
- clone and rebuild my [project](https://github.com/alexlecco/semana-utn) in other place
- update expo-cli and expo-android-app

[I'm using elementary os (linux), expo-cli and android device]

Did something similar happen to someone? How did you resolve it?

my project dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "firebase": "^4.12.1",
    "native-base": "^2.3.10",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-25.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27"`

Answer (score 3):

"magically resolved" deleting `node_modules` folder and running `$ npm install` (AGAIN) and running... (?)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem .I noted that I had switched my app from development to production then back to development .

The problem is that cache was still working on production when I switched to development in the last step .

The log in my console was :

```
Running application "main" with appParams: {"initialProps":{"exp":{"initialUri":"exp://192.168.43.89:19000","manifest":{"iconUrl":"http://192.168.43.89:19001/assets/./assets/icon.png","isVerified":true,"hostUri":"192.168.43.89:19000","version":"1.0.0","slug":"myapp","splash":{"resizeMode":"contain","backgroundColor":"#f7be13","image":"./assets/splash.png","imageUrl":"http://192.168.43.89:19001/assets/./assets/splash.png"},"logUrl":"http://192.168.43.89:19000/logs","privacy":"public","assetBundlePatterns":["**/*"],"primaryColor":"#023C69","android":{"versionCode":1,"package":"com.apppzzzz.myapp","config":{"googleMaps":{"apiKey":""},"googleSignIn":{"certificateHash":"STRING","apiKey":"STRING"}}},"orientation":"portrait","bundleUrl":"http://192.168.43.89:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&minify=true&hot=false&assetPlugin=E%3A%5Ccde%5CTutorial%5CReactNative%5Cmyapp_rnapp%5Cnode_modules%5Cexpo%5Ctools%5ChashAssetFiles.js","updates":{"fallbackToCacheTimeout":0},"ios":{"supportsTablet":true},"packagerOpts":{"dev":false,"lanType":"ip","hostType":"lan","minify":true,"urlRandomness":"ha-wky"},"sdkVersion":"32.0.0","mainModuleName":"node_modules/expo/AppEntry","xde":true,"id":"@anonymous/myapp-dec62901-f76d-419c-8e72-76f2c0e279d7","androidStatusBar":{"backgroundColor":"#f7be10"},"debuggerHost":"192.168.43.89:19001","platforms":["ios","android"],"env":{},"icon":"./assets/icon.png","loadedFromCache":true,"developer":{"tool":"expo-cli","projectRoot":"E:\\cde\\Tutorial\\ReactNative\\myapp_rnapp"},"name":"myapp"},"shell":false}},"rootTag":1}
. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
```

Take note of the `__DEV__ === false`

So I cleared cache in the console using `SHIFT+R`
Then went to my phone and cleared Expo app`s cache

Then restarted my development server , and everything flowed fine !

The log `__DEV__ === false` changed to `__DEV__ === true` , and expo-reloading problems went away !

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled expo app on my phone and reinstalled it. Then I can see application being re-built and loaded back into the phone. Looks like my app is cached in the phone and older version is used even when there is a change to javaScripts.

Comment: In the case of reinstalling. Simple press a from the terminal after running `yarn start` or `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this happened to me while running expo on a windows machine and an iPhone 6S. I was able to get it to "reload" the code by creating an empty expo folder (expo init ReloadProject), going into and restarting the expo client there (expo start).

After accessing it with my phone (and seeing the default app message), and going back into my original project I was able to start expo again with the newer version of the code and see it on the phone working properly.

Aside from this, I also tried reverting code changes, removing node_modules and re-installing, restarting the computer and app on phone, manually clicking reload, trying hot reload and live reload but none of those approaches worked.

Comment: by the way, this was happening to me on windows 10 using a virtual ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by connecting my Windows laptop to wifi (same as Android device) instead of wired connection.

Despite the fact that wifi and wired network are on the same LAN an everything else worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a physical device clear the Expo app's data or uninstall and then reinstall. It worked for me.